# angular 2 add and remove class keyboard when open and close

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

i am creating app in ionic 2 when i click input field keyboard open i want change background image none and when i close the keyboard need to background image

```
<ion-content padding class="bg_gogreen">

<ion-list>
  <ion-item class="input-border">
    <ion-input  type="number" placeholder="Enter your Mobile Number"></ion-input>
    <ion-icon name='ios-contact' class="phone" item-right persianred></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

class name `bg_gogreen` i need to remove this class or change to background image none

```
.bg_gogreen{
    background-image: url(../../img/bg_gogreen.png);
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100%;
}
```

file.ts

```
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';  
   export class MverifyPage{
      constructor(private nav: NavController, 
                  private keyboard: Keyboard
                  ) {

                    this.keyboard = keyboard;
                    this.keyboard.isOpen(this.openCallback);
                    this.keyboard.onClose(this.closeCallback);
                }
                  openCallback(){


                }

                  closeCallback(){

                }
```

two error property keyboard does not exit,and cannot find the name keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```html
<ion-content padding [class.bg_gogreen]='isGreen'">

<ion-list>
  <ion-item class="input-border">
    <ion-input  type="number" placeholder="Enter your Mobile Number" (focus)='isGreen=true' (blur)='isGreen=false'></ion-input>
    <ion-icon name='ios-contact' class="phone" item-right persianred></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

You set the class `bg_gogreen` depending on the component variable `isGreen`. The value of `isGreen` changes on `focus` and `blur`

Don't forget to declare `isGreen`:

```js
export class MverifyPage{
   ...
   isGreen: boolean = false;
   ...
}
```